Is there a way to tell WordPress to use a page theme as the styling of the login page?
I am needing to make a custom login page for my website but need things that are just unavailable (or not available for free) from any of the login page customization plugins. I have created a page template and am needing to see if it is possible to have WordPress use the page template as the stylization of that page?
I have not really tried this way yet as I have been trying to use CF7 for this. I have also tried a custom PHP script, but that was finicky as well.
In case anyone wants to look at the wp-login.php file, I have provided it here.

I think that the WordPress login page is very intentionally not easily or directly themeable. Beyond just login it performs several other functions and it would be very easy for someone to do something that could render login unusable or possibly completely dead, with no resolution short of code or SSH-level fixes.

That said, most theming of the page is done with the login_form and login_enqueue_scripts hooks. If these aren't enough for you, you can also use wp_login_form in your own code, such as in a template, which you can then provide to users to sign in. The default won't change, but you can redirect users at the server level, or using login_url

I have nothing against CF7 (or GF or any other form plugins), but I would greatly discourage those plugins for handling anything related to the login. The entire login process has a lot of security-related features that you might not be aware of, and the core team might add new features as security evolves, and it would be your responsibility to stay on top of each and every one of these.

@ChrisHaas I have found a plugin that will take care of my login page and let me theme it via html without affecting the wp-login.php page.
